# gcc warnings only when there are no errors

Tags: gcc, gcc-warning

Is it possible to tell gcc to show all warnings (like with -Wall) but only if there are no errors? If there are errors - show only them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so. That would require GCC to "cache" all the warnings until it's finished processing the compilation unit, which doesn't sound very useful.

There are utilities like [colorgcc](http://schlueters.de/colorgcc.html) that make the output of GCC a bit more obvious in color terminals - maybe you would find that useful?

<sub>You could turn all the warnings into errors with `-Werror`, thus removing the problem, but that's not what you're after :-)</sub>